# Vuetify - How can I add v-card actions to the right side of a card instead of the default bottom?

Tags: vuetify.js

I'm creating a v-card component using vuetify and would like to find a way to position the v-card-actions button to the right side of the card instead of the bottom. How should I go about doing this?
Please refer to the image below for an example.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XETcc.png)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Update: I've used the [v-row component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-row/) to perform this, specifically wrapping  around 2 divs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it solved the problem.